# Adding new items into PHP array and saving previous size of the array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have the following code so far:

```
$months = array();
$numJoin = date("n",strtotime($me['joinTime']));
$numLast = date('n', strtotime('Dec 31'));
$numCurrent = date("n",strtotime('2016-06-01'));
array_push($months, date("F", strtotime($me['joinTime'])));
for($i = ($numJoin + 1); $i <= $numLast; $i++) {
    if($numCurrent>$numJoin) {
        $dateObj = date_create_from_format('!m', $i);
        array_push($months, $dateObj->format('F'));
    }
    $numCurrent= -1;
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to add into the array current month that kicks in, and save previous months in the array like for example:

Start month is -> May 
June kicks in -> I add June into the array (now I should have May and June in array).

July kicks in -> I add July into the array (now I should have May, June and July in array).

How can I do this achieve this? Current solution works only for +1 month.. I can't add more than 1 month :/

P.S. New item should only be added when the new month kicks in, and previous content of the array should be saved...

Comment: What is the month that you are compare to the array for kicking?

Comment: Are you saving the newly created array in the same variable?

Comment: @FrayneKonok whatever the month is in this variable:         $numJoin = date("n",strtotime($me['joinTime'])); I pick up the value of the month from DB.. This is a join date that is stored into the db ...  This is the start month from which I compare when the new month kicks in ... For instance join date is May -> When June kicks in, I should have 2 months in the array: May and June

Comment: @perkes456, Your answer is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go, you need to check that your month is less than the current month or not. [Check Online](https://3v4l.org/3YYOf)

```
$months = array();
$num = date("n",strtotime($me['joinTime'])); //join month number
$now = date("n"); //Current month number

for($i = $num; $i <= $now; $i++){
    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $i);
    array_push($months, $dateObj->format('F'));
}
print_r($months);
```

Comment: Hi Frayne, does this keeps adding all of the months until the December? :)

Comment: P.S. I need the join month and the the months that will kick in together all in one array... Should I just merge them all in one array?

Comment: depending on the current month, the array kicks updated.

Comment: Yes thats what I need... But I also need the kicked in months and start month to be only in one array, as I'm fetching them in my view as one array, not two... Like this: May (start) , June (kicks in), July(kicks in), all in one array :)

Comment: So than how can you deference the months???? I am little bit confused. Can you clear this problem?

Comment: In you r `$months` array you have all the months listed from joindate to end of the year.

Comment: Okay so for instance user joins on the May... The only current month that he is supposed to see is the May month on the slider that I use... When June month kicks in ... user is supposed to be able to slide between May and June months... So initially start month is always supposed to be in the array... May + new months that kick in... Do you understand me now ? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113320/discussion-between-perkes456-and-frayne-konok).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little confused, but I think this is what you are after... all month names *after* the join month and until current month...

```
$me = array('joinTime'=>'2016-03-01');

$dtCurrent = strtotime($me['joinTime']);
$arrMonths = array();
while($dtCurrent < time()) {
    $dtCurrent = strtotime("+1 month",$dtCurrent);
    $arrMonths[] = date('F',$dtCurrent);
}

var_dump($arrMonths);
```